# Bitmap caching or png?

Tags: flash

In Flash what would be wiser? To use a PNG or import the vector and cache it as bitmap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, you're probably better off using a Bitmap (PNG import) if you're looking for speed.  The only case I can think that a vector makes more sense is if it needs to scale up/down gracefully or the vector is not complex.  Bitmap scaling in Flash can get a bit "chunky" at times.  And complex vector graphics (eg lots of layers, transparency, and gradients) can get processor heavy in a hurry.  So, use your best judgement and test out both cases to see which makes the most sense in your case.